# Website on mobile device, is there a way to make images responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive website for both Desktop and mobile devices. I have an image currently placed in the middle of the screen including buttons in the rop right corner.

My problem is that when the images viewed on a mobile device I find it to be too small?

[image]

I would like to pretty much keep the layout the same but just have the phone image enlarge to the size of the black rectangle I drew. Is there a way to do this? Right now I'm just using standard tags to insert my images and not specifying any size. Ie :

```
<div class="innerdiv">
                <img class="imageCorner" src="logo.png" />
            </div>
```

Any pointers on responsive websites would be really appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

So I tried adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and it shifted everything to the left and cut off the bottom of the page:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the width and/or height of the image to 100%?

Comment: have you defined a meta viewport? using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> inside the <head> tag?

Comment: @Juggernaut tried that yes, no change.

Comment: @BradleyWilson I haven't I'll try it now

Comment: no problem at all, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @BradleyWilson image is larger now but it's shifted it to the left and cutoff the bottom of my page.

Comment: If you add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> you might need to add an @media (max-width:500px){} and in there place custom css for rescaling the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `<img srcset="..." />`? See here: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: this means providing extra images for the different sizes right?

Comment: @KexAri correct. Your viewport meta element instructs the browser not to scale content images, therefore you must provide your own resolution-specific imagery rather than depending on the browser to resize them for you.